# How to read column names of an excel sheet using ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am trying to read column names from excel using ASP.Net. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use data reader and specify the column name

Example:

```
col1 = dr["mycolumnname"].ToString();
```

"mycolumnname" will be column name of your excel sheet

Comment: I think the `mycolumnname` part is what the OP is looking for (i.e. what is unknown). So this would not help.